GPU percentage allocation for a Python class
I'm developing a sort of federated learning environment and it contains a Server class and 10 instances of the Client classes. I train the various clients one after the other and I'd like to specify an upper limit regarding the GPU usage for each client.
For example:
class Client:
    def __init__(self, id:int, neighbors:list, trainloader, valloader, testloader, gpu_fraction, device):
        self.id=id
        self.neighbors = neighbors
        self.model=None
        self.trainloader = trainloader
        self.valloader = valloader
        self.testloader = testloader
        self.gpu_fraction = gpu_fraction
        self.GPU_usage_table=None
        self.device = device   

this is my Client class and I'd like to instantiate every client with a different value of gpu_fraction and then, when a Client executes the training function, I'd like not to use the entire GPU of my PC but just the percentage specified by the gpu_fraction.
I tried with this code
        import tensorflow as tf
        gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=self.gpu_fraction)
        config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
        session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

before executing the training function for every client, but it doesn't seem to work.
To test if this approach works I used the following code:
            nvidia_smi.nvmlInit()
            deviceCount = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetCount()
            for i in range(deviceCount):
                handle = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(i)
                res = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates(handle)
                mem = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
                table.add_row([i, f"{mem.free/1024**2:5.2f}MB/{mem.total/1024**2:5.2f}MB", f"{res.gpu:3.1%}", f"{res.memory:3.1%}"])


What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What do you expect? What do you observe instead?

I mean I set the gpu_fraction equal to 0.01 and I printed the GPU utilization while running and I expected to find a very low percentage instead I found about 95%. To visualize the GPU usage during training I used this code:
nvidia_smi.nvmlInit()
deviceCount = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetCount()
for i in range(deviceCount):
handle = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(i)
res = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates(handle)
mem = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
I don't know if this is the best way to check it but I don't know other methods

Please [edit] your comment into your question, preferably in a code block. That way, it will actually be readable. Comments are for asking clarifications, questions should stand on their own. Thank you once again.
